# Problems using MemoryMappedFile class on Mono

Tags: c#-4.0, mono, memory-mapped-files

I'm trying to port a new versio of the Isis2 library from .NET on Windows to Mono/Linux.  This new code uses MemoryMappedFile objects, and I suddenly am running into issues with the Mono.Posix.Helper library.  I believe that my issues would vanish if I could successfully compile and run the following test program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;

namespace foobar
{
  class Program
  {
    static int CAPACITY = 100000;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("test", CAPACITY);
        MemoryMappedViewAccessor mva = mmf.CreateViewAccessor();
        for (int n = 0; n < CAPACITY; n++)
        {
            byte b = (byte)(n & 0xFF);
            mva.Write<byte>(n, ref b);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

... at present, when I try to compile this on Mono I get a bewildering set of linker errors: it seems unable to find libMonoPosixHelper.so, although my LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes the directory containing that file, and then if I manage to get past that stage, I get "System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented." at runtime.  Yet I've looked at the Mono implementation of the CreateNew method; it seems fully implemented, and the same is true for the CreateViewAccessor method.  Thus I have a sense that something is going badly wrong when linking to the Mono libraries.

Does anyone have experience with MemoryMappedFile objects under Mono?  I see quite a few questions about this kind of issue here and on other sites, but all seem to be old threads...

Comment: that class has some NIEs in it, I think you need to implement a missing overload or something (and contribute it back to mono)

Comment: Knocte, I think this may be the issue.  I've been doing simple experiments and it looks more and more as if Mono may not have a correct implementation of the "pure in-memory" case for MemoryMappedFiles.  On .NET, you can have a memory-mapped file with no disk file behind it, and people use this heavily.  But it seems that on Linux, there may need to be a real file (not such a big deal), and that perhaps Mono just doesn't handle that case correctly.  On top of which, something is very odd about the way the linker handles this particular DLL, but you can work around that issue...

Comment: you're wrong, MemoryMappedFile generally works in Linux (the implementation is very complete), but it seems you found an edge case in which it doesn't. You should come up with a testcase that works in .NET and not in Linux, and contribute the fix, should be easy

Comment: The one shown above works in .NET on Windows and not on Linux.  That's my point.  Try it.  You'll get an error.  Then try changing the file name to "/tmp/test".  You'll get a different error.  In fact no matter what you do you'll get an error on Linux, and no matter what you do the Windows version runs happily (and correctly; this is a short example of something much more sophisticated that I am working with in Isis2 now on Windows)

Comment: right, then this is an edge case, work with it to find the proper bugfix for mono

Answer (score 3):

OK, I figured at least part of this out by inspection of the Mono code implementing this API.  In fact they implemented CreateNew in a way that departs pretty drastically from the .NET API, causing these methods to behave very differently from what you would expect.

For CreateNew, they actually require that the file name you specify be the name of an existing Linux file of size at least as large as the capacity you specify, and also do some other checks for access permissions (of course), exclusive access (which is at odds with sharing...) and to make sure the capacity you requested is > 0.  So if you had the file previously open, or someone else does, this will fail -- in contrast to .NET, where you explicitly use memory-mapped files for sharing.

In contrast, CreateOrOpen appears to be "more or less" correctly implemented; switching to this version seems to solve the problem.  To get the effect of CreateNew, do a Delete first, wrapping it in a try/catch to catch IOException if the file doesn't exist.  Then use File.WriteAllBytes to create a file with your desired content.  Then call CreateOrOpen.  Now this sounds dumb, but it works. Obviously you can't guarantee atomicity this way (three operations rather than one), but at least you get the desired functionality.

I can live with these restrictions as it works out, but they may surprise others, and are totally different from the .NET API definition for MemoryMappedFile.

As for my linking issues, as far as I can tell there is a situation in which Mono doesn't use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH you specify correctly and hence can't find the .so file or .dll file you used.  I'll post more on this if I can precisely pin down the circumstances -- on this one, I've worked around the issue by statically linking to the library.

Comment: great analysis! given that you know a lot about this, you would be the perfect person to contribute a fix to upstream mono code

Comment: I've been looking at it -- I'm running into issues now with the Mono asynchronous send (BeginSendTo).  Fixing this stuff might be the right thing to do.  The odd thing is that the code quality actually looks very high, so it comes as kind of a surprise that CreateNew wasn't debugged (in fact even CreateOrOpen isn't fully debugged).  On the other hand this particular module is full of [Mono ToDo] and throw NotImplemented lines.  Maybe I'm just on the bleeding edge...

Comment: Mono's code quality is very high. The only problem is that they have limited resources and you cannot expect them to implement every corner case correctly. You could do `git blame` to know when and who developed it... then, with that nickname you can probably chat with the developer in irc://irc.gnome.org/mono